# Table top town used by advertisers

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, the-twilight-zone

A man begins to suspect there is something wrong in his city, in which, we notice, product offers are repeatedly made to him.  The denouement is that the town all died in an industrial accident and their spirits are being used in an advertising experiment, and they are living in a table top model of the town.
I am looking for the name of this episode from the TV Show *Twilight Zone*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**[The Tunnel under the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tunnel_under_the_World)**.

It originally appeared as a short story in Galaxy magazine. Since then it has appeared in several TV and film versions, including [a Season 2 episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Out_of_the_Unknown_episodes#Series_2) of *Out of the Unknown*.

Details which match your synopsis:

- product offers / adverts: yest for a variety of products, often with loud jingles
- rebuilt in miniture
- not spirits as such but rebuilt as tiny robots

<sub>For bonus points, *"[How would I know if I were a 1 mm tall robot?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/40633/19333)"*</sub>

Comment: I was thinking of this too, but it does not appear to have been a Twilight Zone episode.

Comment: Perhaps @michael mis-remembered after seeing it on TV?

Comment: that's funny, thanks for the name. I looked it up and I can't figure where I might have seen it.

Comment: @michael - see the Wikipedia link for details. You probably saw it on the BBC series, *"Out of the Unknown"*.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like that one made it to Youtube...